Как запустить функцию скрипта, который уже запущен из консоли | NodeJS
nodejs скрипт был запущен на сервере через консоль.
nodejs script.js

Можно ли как-то прям из консоли выполнить одну из функцию этого скрипта?
Например:


//script.js
let timer = null;

function stopLoop() {
  self.clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}

timer = self.setInterval(() => {
  console.log('loop');
}, 1000);
<div>Без него не дает вставить фрагмент</div>



Запускаю скрипт:
nodejs script.js

И в любой момент времени вызываю его функцию:
nodejs script.js:stopLoop

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Могу предложить посмотреть в сторону readline


Как запустить функцию скрипта, который уже запущен из консоли

Для этого сам скрипт должен уметь обрабатывать ввод из той консоли. Вот небольшой пример. Вводи команды (stop или close) скрипт будет реагировать на них
const readline = require('node:readline/promises')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});

rl.on('line', line => {
    const com = line.toLowerCase()
    if (com === 'stop') stopLoop()
    if (com === 'close') rl.close()
});

rl.on('close', _ => {
    console.log('Обработка ввода завершена');
});

const timer = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('loop');
}, 1000);

function stopLoop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log('Таймер остановлен');
}


Добавил код в скрипт, но почему-то не получается запустить его из терминала. (команда не найдена) Можешь скинуть, как ты обращаешься из терминала к скрипту? В документации readline вижу только код, но не не могу найти вызов.

@SireIMPACTUS, обращаюсь как обычно - node test.js где test.js это файл с этой программкой.

Потом можно писать команды stop или close... Ну и Enter давить не забывай после команды...
